# How can I fix Jupyter Lab error?? Failed validating settings (@jupyterlab/htmlviewer-extension:plugin):

Tags: jupyter-lab, miniconda

When I run Jupyter Lab in the conda environment, the following error appears. And in Jupiter Lab, the run icon etc. has disappeared and has been replaced with text. What should I do??

Failed validating settings (@jupyterlab/htmlviewer-extension:plugin): Additional properties are not allowed ('trustByDefault' was unexpected)

```
Failed validating 'additionalProperties' in schema:
    {'additionalProperties': False,
     'definitions': {'toolbarItem': {'additionalProperties': False,
                                     'properties': {'args': {'title': 'Command '
                                                                      'arguments',
                                                             'type': 'object'},
                                                    'command': {'default': '',
                                                                'title': 'Command '
                                                                         'id',
                                                                'type': 'string'},
                                                    'disabled': {'default': False,
                                                                 'title': 'Whether '
                                                                          'the '
                                                                          'item '
                                                                          'is '
                                                                          'ignored '
                                                                          'or '
                                                                          'not',
                                                                 'type': 'boolean'},
                                                    'icon': {'description': 'If '
                                                                            'defined, '
                                                                            'it '
                                                                            'will '
                                                                            'override '
                                                                            'the '
                                                                            'command '
                                                                            'icon',
                                                             'title': 'Item '
                                                                      'icon '
                                                                      'id',
                                                             'type': 'string'},
                                                    'label': {'description': 'If '
                                                                             'defined, '
                                                                             'it '
                                                                             'will '
                                                                             'override '
                                                                             'the '
                                                                             'command '
                                                                             'label',
                                                              'title': 'Item '
                                                                       'label',
                                                              'type': 'string'},
                                                    'name': {'title': 'Unique '
                                                                      'name',
                                                             'type': 'string'},
                                                    'rank': {'default': 50,
                                                             'minimum': 0,
                                                             'title': 'Item '
                                                                      'rank',
                                                             'type': 'number'},
                                                    'type': {'enum': ['command',
                                                                      'spacer'],
                                                             'title': 'Item '
                                                                      'type',
                                                             'type': 'string'}},
                                     'required': ['name'],
                                     'type': 'object'}},
     'description': 'HTML Viewer settings.',
     'jupyter.lab.setting-icon': 'ui-components:html5',
     'jupyter.lab.setting-icon-label': 'HTML Viewer',
     'jupyter.lab.toolbars': {'HTML Viewer': [{'name': 'refresh',
                                               'rank': 10},
                                              {'name': 'trust',
                                               'rank': 20}]},
     'jupyter.lab.transform': True,
     'properties': {'toolbar': {'default': [],
                                'description': 'Note: To disable a toolbar '
                                               'item,\n'
                                               'copy it to User '
                                               'Preferences and add the\n'
                                               '"disabled" key. The '
                                               'following example will '
                                               'disable the refresh item:\n'
                                               '{\n'
                                               '  "toolbar": [\n'
                                               '    {\n'
                                               '      "name": "refresh",\n'
                                               '      "disabled": true\n'
                                               '    }\n'
                                               '  ]\n'
                                               '}\n'
                                               '\n'
                                               'Toolbar description:',
                                'items': {'$ref': '#/definitions/toolbarItem'},
                                'title': 'HTML viewer toolbar items',
                                'type': 'array'}},
     'title': 'HTML Viewer',
     'type': 'object'}

On instance:
    {'toolbar': [{'command': '',
                  'disabled': False,
                  'name': 'refresh',
                  'rank': 10},
                 {'command': '',
                  'disabled': False,
                  'name': 'trust',
                  'rank': 20}],
     'trustByDefault': False}
```

[W 2024-01-18 10:15:42.009 LabApp] Failed validating settings (@jupyterlab/htmlviewer-extension:plugin): Additional properties are not allowed ('trustByDefault' was unexpected)

```
Failed validating 'additionalProperties' in schema:
    {'additionalProperties': False,
     'definitions': {'toolbarItem': {'additionalProperties': False,
                                     'properties': {'args': {'title': 'Command '
                                                                      'arguments',
                                                             'type': 'object'},
                                                    'command': {'default': '',
                                                                'title': 'Command '
                                                                         'id',
                                                                'type': 'string'},
                                                    'disabled': {'default': False,
                                                                 'title': 'Whether '
                                                                          'the '
                                                                          'item '
                                                                          'is '
                                                                          'ignored '
                                                                          'or '
                                                                          'not',
                                                                 'type': 'boolean'},
                                                    'icon': {'description': 'If '
                                                                            'defined, '
                                                                            'it '
                                                                            'will '
                                                                            'override '
                                                                            'the '
                                                                            'command '
                                                                            'icon',
                                                             'title': 'Item '
                                                                      'icon '
                                                                      'id',
                                                             'type': 'string'},
                                                    'label': {'description': 'If '
                                                                             'defined, '
                                                                             'it '
                                                                             'will '
                                                                             'override '
                                                                             'the '
                                                                             'command '
                                                                             'label',
                                                              'title': 'Item '
                                                                       'label',
                                                              'type': 'string'},
                                                    'name': {'title': 'Unique '
                                                                      'name',
                                                             'type': 'string'},
                                                    'rank': {'default': 50,
                                                             'minimum': 0,
                                                             'title': 'Item '
                                                                      'rank',
                                                             'type': 'number'},
                                                    'type': {'enum': ['command',
                                                                      'spacer'],
                                                             'title': 'Item '
                                                                      'type',
                                                             'type': 'string'}},
                                     'required': ['name'],
                                     'type': 'object'}},
     'description': 'HTML Viewer settings.',
     'jupyter.lab.setting-icon': 'ui-components:html5',
     'jupyter.lab.setting-icon-label': 'HTML Viewer',
     'jupyter.lab.toolbars': {'HTML Viewer': [{'name': 'refresh',
                                               'rank': 10},
                                              {'name': 'trust',
                                               'rank': 20}]},
     'jupyter.lab.transform': True,
     'properties': {'toolbar': {'default': [],
                                'description': 'Note: To disable a toolbar '
                                               'item,\n'
                                               'copy it to User '
                                               'Preferences and add the\n'
                                               '"disabled" key. The '
                                               'following example will '
                                               'disable the refresh item:\n'
                                               '{\n'
                                               '  "toolbar": [\n'
                                               '    {\n'
                                               '      "name": "refresh",\n'
                                               '      "disabled": true\n'
                                               '    }\n'
                                               '  ]\n'
                                               '}\n'
                                               '\n'
                                               'Toolbar description:',
                                'items': {'$ref': '#/definitions/toolbarItem'},
                                'title': 'HTML viewer toolbar items',
                                'type': 'array'}},
     'title': 'HTML Viewer',
     'type': 'object'}

On instance:
    {'toolbar': [{'command': '',
                  'disabled': False,
                  'name': 'refresh',
                  'rank': 10},
                 {'command': '',
                  'disabled': False,
                  'name': 'trust',
                  'rank': 20}],
     'trustByDefault': False}
```

[I 2024-01-18 10:15:42.198 LabApp] Build is up to date
[W 2024-01-18 10:15:42.566 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2024-01-18 10:15:42.566 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2024-01-18 10:15:42.572 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2024-01-18 10:15:42.574 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2024-01-18 10:15:42.605 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2024-01-18 10:15:42.607 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2024-01-18 10:15:42.613 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2024-01-18 10:15:42.614 ServerApp] Config option `template_path` not recognized by `LenvsTocHTMLExporter`.  Did you mean one of: `extra_template_paths, template_name, template_paths`?
[W 2024-01-18 10:15:42.784 LabApp] Failed validating settings (@jupyterlab/htmlviewer-extension:plugin): Additional properties are not allowed ('trustByDefault' was unexpected)

```
Failed validating 'additionalProperties' in schema:
    {'additionalProperties': False,
     'definitions': {'toolbarItem': {'additionalProperties': False,
                                     'properties': {'args': {'title': 'Command '
                                                                      'arguments',
                                                             'type': 'object'},
                                                    'command': {'default': '',
                                                                'title': 'Command '
                                                                         'id',
                                                                'type': 'string'},
                                                    'disabled': {'default': False,
                                                                 'title': 'Whether '
                                                                          'the '
                                                                          'item '
                                                                          'is '
                                                                          'ignored '
                                                                          'or '
                                                                          'not',
                                                                 'type': 'boolean'},
                                                    'icon': {'description': 'If '
                                                                            'defined, '
                                                                            'it '
                                                                            'will '
                                                                            'override '
                                                                            'the '
                                                                            'command '
                                                                            'icon',
                                                             'title': 'Item '
                                                                      'icon '
                                                                      'id',
                                                             'type': 'string'},
                                                    'label': {'description': 'If '
                                                                             'defined, '
                                                                             'it '
                                                                             'will '
                                                                             'override '
                                                                             'the '
                                                                             'command '
                                                                             'label',
                                                              'title': 'Item '
                                                                       'label',
                                                              'type': 'string'},
                                                    'name': {'title': 'Unique '
                                                                      'name',
                                                             'type': 'string'},
                                                    'rank': {'default': 50,
                                                             'minimum': 0,
                                                             'title': 'Item '
                                                                      'rank',
                                                             'type': 'number'},
                                                    'type': {'enum': ['command',
                                                                      'spacer'],
                                                             'title': 'Item '
                                                                      'type',
                                                             'type': 'string'}},
                                     'required': ['name'],
                                     'type': 'object'}},
     'description': 'HTML Viewer settings.',
     'jupyter.lab.setting-icon': 'ui-components:html5',
     'jupyter.lab.setting-icon-label': 'HTML Viewer',
     'jupyter.lab.toolbars': {'HTML Viewer': [{'name': 'refresh',
                                               'rank': 10},
                                              {'name': 'trust',
                                               'rank': 20}]},
     'jupyter.lab.transform': True,
     'properties': {'toolbar': {'default': [],
                                'description': 'Note: To disable a toolbar '
                                               'item,\n'
                                               'copy it to User '
                                               'Preferences and add the\n'
                                               '"disabled" key. The '
                                               'following example will '
                                               'disable the refresh item:\n'
                                               '{\n'
                                               '  "toolbar": [\n'
                                               '    {\n'
                                               '      "name": "refresh",\n'
                                               '      "disabled": true\n'
                                               '    }\n'
                                               '  ]\n'
                                               '}\n'
                                               '\n'
                                               'Toolbar description:',
                                'items': {'$ref': '#/definitions/toolbarItem'},
                                'title': 'HTML viewer toolbar items',
                                'type': 'array'}},
     'title': 'HTML Viewer',
     'type': 'object'}

On instance:
    {'toolbar': [{'command': '',
                  'disabled': False,
                  'name': 'refresh',
                  'rank': 10},
                 {'command': '',
                  'disabled': False,
                  'name': 'trust',
                  'rank': 20}],
     'trustByDefault': False}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/carJ7.png)

I tried to install nbextension...